# PyDoIt: Sharing tasks definitions across modules

Tags: python, doit

Here is a simpler version of the problem I am facing. I have a task in `dodo.py` file. This task has access to a module level variable `name`.

```
# dodo.py
name = 'John'

def task_hello():
    return {
        'actions': [f'echo Hello {name}!']
    }
```

Now I want to have different versions of this task. A naive way of doing this would be the following.

```
# dodo1.py
name = 'Tim'

def task_hello():
    return {
        'actions': [f'echo Hello {name}!']
    }
```

And

```
# dodo2.py
name = 'Julia'

def task_hello():
    return {
        'actions': [f'echo Hello {name}!']
    }
```

I do want multiple `dodo` modules. However, I do not want to copy the task definition.

Note that, although I have mentioned just one task here for simplicity, I have a set of inter-dependent tasks and subtasks. Also, I do not want to use command line parameters and prefer to have multiple `config` files.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I ended up doing this. This solves the problem. But I am open to more elegant solutions.

dodo1.py

```
def mk_task_hello(name):
    yield {
        'basename': 'hello',
        'name': 'world',
        'actions': [f'echo Hello {name}!']
    }
```

dodo2.py

```
from dodo1 import mk_task_hello

name = 'Tim'


def task_hello():
    yield from mk_task_hello(name)
```

dodo3.py

```
from dodo1 import mk_task_hello

name = 'Julia'


def task_hello():
    yield from mk_task_hello(name)
```

`dodo1.py` is the main task implementation module whereas `dodo2.py` and `dodo3.py` are different instantiations. Note the `basename` field in task dictionary. This is necessary for the task dependencies (not shown in the example above) to work.

Comment: Tha's the whole point of class, since you can easily wrap  `task_hello` in a class, import that class and call it like i did in my example @dips

Comment: `pydoit` automatically extracts tasks from the module. (all methods with prefix `task_`). This doesn't work with class. This is more of a pydoit question than a python question. But I can not add `pydoit` tag due to my low reputation.

Comment: I don’t think there is a pydoit tag to begin with otherwise you would have seen it, anyways seems like I cannot help you much out here